# Почему не передается значение переменной в шаблон?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет!
Есть переменная `$testVar = 'Тест!';` в файле wp-content\mu-plugins\test.php.
Каким образом вывести значение этой переменной в шаблоне, который подключается через `get_template_part('templates/header');`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@scorp24](/users/19185/scorp24), в парадигме вордпресса будет правильным обернуть получение этого значения в функцию и вызывать ее в нужном месте.

Comment: Etki, спасибо за ответ - в точку!